# error:NsIvalidArgumentException [_NSCFConstantString ObjectAtIndex:]:

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, core-bluetooth

I'm using table view in view controller.tableviewcell shows the same data only in the row.I'm having action button in the view controller. If I pressed a button the output shown in the tableviewcell it is concept. I don't know how to allocate string as a array. I'm using device as nsarray

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 self.label.text = @"";
 device=[[NSString alloc]init];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {   
 return 2;
 }
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
//cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
//if (!cell)
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];



UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil)
{
    cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}


   cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",device];
   cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return cell;
 }

-(void)peripheralManagerDidConnectPeripheral:(PeripheralManager *)manager
{
device = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", manager.deviceName];
[self.deviceTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: maybe it is to early in the morning and I dont get it, but where do you get the NSInvalidArgumentException?

Comment: You use device as an NSArray and you allocate it as NSString ? Maybe you can do device = [NSMutableArray alloc] init] and in the peripheralManagerDidConnectPeripheral you put : [device addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@", manager.deviceName]]; No ?

Comment: yes correct..but now i want to set indexpathrow..Can u help me

Comment: no error ..nsarray declares the selector 'addobject:'

Comment: Declare device as an NSMutableArray ;) You cannot addObject in a NSArray. And for your indexpath you can use the method indexPathForCell: on the tableView, given a pointer to a UITableViewCell it returns its indexPath.

Comment: error: __NSArrayM ObjectAtIndex  index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: Wich line ? You have an empty array. You tried to call [array objectAtIndex:0]. 0 is beyond the bounds of an empty array

Comment: cell.textlabel.text=[device objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];

Comment: Are you sure that your device NSMutableArray is not nil ?

Comment: running sucessfully but tableviewcell is empty

Comment: device name not displayed in the tableviewcell

Comment: what's the size of your NSMutableArray ?

Comment: can u send your email address ?i will send the code to you.

Comment: Give me your adress mail and i will contact you... Don't forgot do delete it later ;)